# openpyxl is overwriting any work done by win32 macro in Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, pywin32, win32com

I am currently writing a script that requires me to update data in an Excel sheet and run a macro. After running the macro, I am trying to save the file using win32, in order to be able to run through a similar process again. However, I have linked everything back to a weird issue with win32 and openpyxl. It seems that if I run the macro using win32, save the file and open it, everything looks exactly how it should. But if I then use openpyxl to add something to that file after running the macro, the entire results from the macro are then deleted. For example, the macro fills in cells A4:H23 with the correct data, but then after saving with win32 and reopening and editing with openpyxl, if I try to add any value to cell A3 afterwards and open up the file, the only thing that shows is the value in A3 and nothing that the macro should have done. I can open the sheet manually and add the number and resave it perfectly fine, but when I use openpyxl to do so, it clears all the macro results. I have included my code below for reference. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
import win32com.client
import re
import time

Macro1 = r"C:\Users\...\Documents\Macro1Demo.xlsm"
Macro2 = r"C:\Users\...\Documents\Macro2Demo.xlsm"
MiddleManTest = r"C:\Users\...\Documents\MiddleManTest.xlsm"
MiddleMan2 = r"C:\Users\...\Documents\MiddleMan2.xlsm"
DistrictList = r"C:\Users\...\Documents\DistrictList.xlsx"

Macro1WB = load_workbook(filename = Macro1, keep_vba = True)
Macro2WB = load_workbook(filename = Macro2, keep_vba = True)
MM2WB = load_workbook(filename = MiddleMan2, keep_vba = True)
ListWB = load_workbook(filename = DistrictList, keep_vba = True)

ListSheet = ListWB['Sheet1']
M1Sheet = Macro1WB['Entry']
M2Sheet = Macro2WB['Raw']

for i in range(2,3):
    Macro1WB['Entry']['A2'].value = ListWB['Sheet1']['A' + str(i)].value
    Macro1WB['Entry']['B2'].value = ListWB['Sheet1']['B' + str(i)].value
    OrgName = Macro1WB['Entry']['A2'].value
    DistrictName = Macro1WB['Entry']['B2'].value
    Macro1WB.save(Macro1)
    SimpleOrgName = re.sub('[/\:*?<>|"]','',OrgName)
    SimpleDistrictName = re.sub('[/\:*?<>|"]','',DistrictName)
    NewFileName = SimpleOrgName + "(" + SimpleDistrictName + ")"
    print(Macro1WB['Entry']['A2'].value,Macro1WB['Entry']['B2'].value)
    print("Org/District Copied.")

    if os.path.exists(r"C:\Users\...\Documents\Macro1Demo.xlsm"):
        xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.application")
        xl.visible = True
        workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(r"C:\Users\...\Documents\Macro1Demo.xlsm"))
        xl.Application.Run("Macro1Demo.xlsm!Module1.AdvancedFilter")
        print("Data filtered.")
        workbook.SaveAs(MiddleMan2)
        xl.Application.Quit()

        MM2WB['Entry']['A3'] = i
        MM2WB.save(MiddleMan2)
```

Comment: I've had similiar issues with openpyxl before, which led to me switch to [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/), which solved all of my problems. xlwings might be able to do everything you're looking for here (e.g. running VBA macros from python), without requiring you to use openpyxl and win32com simultaneously.

Comment: @riskypenguin I tried to switch over to xlwings and I seem to still be getting errors with the macro but this time it won't even run completely. It seems to error out on any macro I try to run, on the first line of that macro. I don't know how comfortable you are with xlwings but do you know a possible fix for this?

Comment: Without knowing more about the error it's hard to tell. To call a macro using xlwings I use `wb.macro("MyMacroName")(param1, param2)`.